# How to scale down all images proportionally when Print to PDF on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, printing

I'm using Google Chrome(current latest v56), and feel its Print to PDF function very useful. But there is a small problem.

- Case 1: If the widest image on the webpage is too wide, 2000px for eample, the text on the PDF becomes very small.
- Case 2: If the widest image on the webpage is only 1000px, the text on the PDF becomes twice the size of case 1, and the text size looks comfortable.

This can be demonstrated with the following html snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
<title> circle </title>

<style type="text/css">
img  {
    width: 2000px; /* Change this value to experience it */
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p>Check the text size<p>

<img src="_circle.png" />

<p>END</p>

</body>
</html>
```

So my question is: Is there a way to scale down every images on the webpage to a ratio, for example, 80%, 70% or 60%, so that the text size look good on the PDF. The scale-down adjustment can be temporal(e.g. in F12 console), because I just want generate PDF occasionally and manually.

Answer (score 0):

I forge a JavaScript snippet to shrink all qualified `<img>`s to 70% size.

```
imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img')
for(var i in imgs) {
    if(isNaN(i))
        continue
    cimg = imgs[i]
    if(cimg.getAttribute('class')=="confluence-embedded-image")
        cimg.width = cimg.width * 0.7
}
```

Before I open Print dialog, I open F12 console and paste above code in; all images will be 70% of their former visual size. Now print it.